# How to fit a Gaussian approximation to the likelihood curve at maximum?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, gaussian

If we find maximum likelihood of,
$$
P(D_i\mid F_\text{true}) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi e_i^2}} \exp\left[ \frac{-(F_i - F_\text{true})^2}{2e_i^2} \right]
$$
and calculate the $\log$ likelihood as:
$$
\log\mathcal L = -\frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \log(2\pi e_i^2) + \frac{(F_i - F_\text{true})^2}{e_i^2} \right]
$$
and calculate $f$ estimate as:
$$
F_\text{est} = \frac{\sum w_i F_i}{\sum w_i}; \quad w_i = \frac 1 {e_i^2}
$$
and then want to fitting a Gaussian approximation to the likelihood curve at maximum. then my question is how they calculate the standard deviation of this Gaussian approximation as:
$$
\sigma_\text{est} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N w_i \right)^{-1/2}
$$

[References from [this](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/03/11/frequentism-and-bayesianism-a-practical-intro/) blog]